# GUI-button to exit loop, Move-Item Job

Tags: powershell, loops, user-interface, button, break

I'm struggling to break the `while` loop when the "Off" button is being pressed. 
Instead, after starting the moving process, I am running into an endless loop.

```
$objForm.Controls.Add($StartButton)
$objForm.Controls.Add($OffButton)

$OffButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OffButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(340,105)
$OffButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,28)
$OffButton.Text = 'Off'
$OffButton.Name = 'Off'
$OffButton.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::New("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11)
$OffButton.Add_Click({$script:AktiveLoop = $False})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OffButton)

$StartButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$StartButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(340,135)
$StartButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,28)
$StartButton.Text = 'Start'
$StartButton.Name = 'Start'
$StartButton.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::New("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11)
$StartButton.Add_Click({
    $script:AktiveLoop = $true

    while ($script:AktiveLoop -eq $true) {
        Move-Item $source -Destination $destination
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1.0

        if ($script:AktiveLoop = $False) {
            break
        }
    }
})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Where in your code do you define `$source` and `$destination`?

Comment: further up. it would not let me paste the entire code in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is discussion about using [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Application_DoEvents), the fact that your button 'Off' click does not seem to be fired has to do with the `Start-Sleep` you are putting in the loop.

`Start-Sleep` makes the form unresponsive. If you use `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` instead the button click events are processed.

Also, from a user point of view, it is best to disable the 'Off 'button when the form is first drawn and toggle the enabled startus of both buttons inside te `Click` events.

For this I have made some changes to the code given in the example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$objForm   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$OffButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OffButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(340,105)
$OffButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,28)
$OffButton.Text = 'Off'
$OffButton.Name = 'Off'
$OffButton.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::New("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11)
# initially disable the 'Off' button
$OffButton.Enabled   = $false
$OffButton.Add_Click({
    $script:AktiveLoop   = $false
    $OffButton.Enabled   = $false
    $StartButton.Enabled = $true

})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OffButton)

$StartButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$StartButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(340,135)
$StartButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,28)
$StartButton.Text = 'Start'
$StartButton.Name = 'Start'
$StartButton.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::New("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11)
# initially enable the 'Off' button
$StartButton.Enabled = $true
$StartButton.Add_Click({
    # switch the buttons Enabled status so the user can not click the same button twice
    $OffButton.Enabled   = $true
    $StartButton.Enabled = $false
    $script:AktiveLoop   = $true

    while ($script:AktiveLoop) {
        # perform some action here. (added -WhatIf here for testing)
        Move-Item $source -Destination $destination -WhatIf

        # Start-Sleep makes the form unresponsive, so don't use that.

        # DoEvents() suspends the current thread and processes 
        # window messages like a click on the 'Off' button.
        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
    }
})
$objForm.Controls.Add($StartButton)


[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
$objForm.Dispose()
```

p.s. You added the buttons to the form even before you have defined them, so I removed that.

Hope this helps